# How do I tell which kernel module is servicing a /dev device?

Tags: linux, drivers, device, kernel-modules

How do I find out which kernel module (as seen by typing lsmod) is servicing a particular device in /dev ?

In other words, say I have a device, /dev/mouse0 and I want to find out which kernel module is installed to service that device. How do I do that?

Another way to look at this is, some loaded kernel modules associate themselves with a device in /dev. How does one find out which device(s) a module is "attached" to?

Comment: It's better to talk about _kernel driver_ rather than _kernel module_, as a _kernel driver_ can be built both built-in and as a module, but that doesn't affect which driver drives a device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can usually find this information by digging through `/sys` if you're on a 2.6 kernel.

e.g.

```
$ ls -la /dev/input/mouse1   
crw-r----- 1 root root 13, 33 2010-03-08 15:56 /dev/input/mouse1
$ ls -la /sys/class/input/mouse1/device/driver 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2010-05-12 23:33 /sys/class/input/mouse1/device/driver -> ../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/usbhid
```

So the driver in this case is `usbhid`. There might be a better/neater way of doing this but I find digging in sysfs usually gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this will help finding the module (though it should) but you can use `lsof` to see what is accessing the particular device file. `lsof /dev/mouse0` for example, though you can do more with the commandline options to lsof

more examples of how to use `lsof`
http://wikis.sun.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=49906332

Comment: lsof won't show you the name of the module. lsof only shows which userspace programs have the device node open.